# Can we make use of variable inside method definition within a class without defining it outside the method and inside class apriori?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm beginner in pytorch and python, I was looking as some examples of codes and

I'm wondering the use of `d` in the following codes:

```
def train_and_eval(self):
        self.entity_idxs = {d.entities[i]:i for i in range(len(d.entities))}
        self.relation_idxs = {d.relations[i]:i for i in range(len(d.relations))}
```

in the d.entities[i], I didn't see anywhere before the code where d is defined.

So what could this mean? can you explain the codes? I don't know if my question is clear or not, please ask if you need extra backgroud.

I can also show the beginning of code:

```
class Experiment:

    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.0005, ent_vec_dim=200, rel_vec_dim=200, 
                 num_iterations=500, batch_size=128, decay_rate=0., cuda=False, 
                 input_dropout=0.3, hidden_dropout1=0.4, hidden_dropout2=0.5,
                 label_smoothing=0.):
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.ent_vec_dim = ent_vec_dim
        self.rel_vec_dim = rel_vec_dim
        self.num_iterations = num_iterations
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.decay_rate = decay_rate
        self.label_smoothing = label_smoothing
        self.cuda = cuda
        self.kwargs = {"input_dropout": input_dropout, "hidden_dropout1": hidden_dropout1,
                       "hidden_dropout2": hidden_dropout2}

    def get_data_idxs(self, data):
        data_idxs = [(self.entity_idxs[data[i][0]], self.relation_idxs[data[i][1]], \
                      self.entity_idxs[data[i][2]]) for i in range(len(data))]
        return data_idxs
```

You see that here they were using `self.entity_idxs` in the first method of the class and it was not defined anywhere eiter. and this was used again later on in the class which is the first snipped of code i provided.

Comment: Any chance you can post a [complete standalone program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you're asking about? If not, could you at least link to a source where we can find the complete source code in question?

Comment: The source code is here sir: https://github.com/ibalazevic/TuckER/blob/master/main.py

Comment: `d` is a global variable defined [here](https://github.com/ibalazevic/TuckER/blob/a70075f6494198dc0a40ae97f0eb46525660bbde/main.py#L194) ... and `self.entity_ids` is an instance variable, defined [here](https://github.com/ibalazevic/TuckER/blob/a70075f6494198dc0a40ae97f0eb46525660bbde/main.py#L102)

Comment: Oh Ok! also how did you do the highlighting and hyperlinking trick?

Comment: @user42493 click on the line-number in github, that also provides permalinks, etc

Comment: @user42493 note, I literally did `ctrl-f` and then looked for `d = ` and `self.entitiy_ids =`...

Comment: I still not understanding completely,  can you also explain do we have to call train_and_eval() to initialize self.entitiy_ids before we can use it in other method like get_data_idxs?

Comment: A good way to figure it out is by looking at the imports in a python file. e.g `Data` is imported from load_data in the first line of your code main.py (`Data` can be a installed package or a module in python path) - in this case, it is a module.

Comment: This can be useful for you to go over once - https://dev.to/codemouse92/dead-simple-python-project-structure-and-imports-38c6

Comment: @user42493 yes. you would have to call `train_and_eval` or else `self.entity_ids` won't exist.